# Flask handling multiple errors

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

I have a simple app made in Flask. It uses only POST method.
It takes 2 numbers (in json) and adds them up.

```
{"a": 1, "b": 1}
```

The application responds with the sum of these numbers (also in json).

```
{"sum": 2}
```

The code looks like this:

```
@appFlask.route('sum', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    data = request.get_json()
    return jsonify({'sum': data['a'] + data['b']})
```

I would like to do error handling. The problem is that there are a lot of these errors, e.g. for the following calls, they should return "400 Bad Request" or if the file isn't in json.

```
{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}
{"a", "a":1, "b":1}
{}
{"a":1}
{"a":0, "b":1}
```

How can i make it in the simplest way? Is there a way to do this in one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use catch the error and then you can return "400 Bad Request" and return an example of data and it's validations to the user.

```py
@appFlask.route('sum', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    try:
       data = request.get_json()
       # check if a or b is not 0
       if data['a'] == 0 or data['b'] == 0:
           raise Exception("Error occurred")
       return jsonify({'sum': data['a'] + data['b']})
    except Exception as e:
       return "400 Bad Request"
```

All the other calls mentioned in example will generate error which will be cached.

You don't need to worry for `{"a":1, "b":1, "c":1}` as it will not affect the code but if you want to consider it bad request you need to do a check for it.

You surely need to do checks according to your needs as there is no built in function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass along the HTTP status code with your return statement.

```
@appFlask.route('/sum', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    try:
       data = request.get_json()
       if len(data.keys()) != 2 and all(data.values()): #
           return "Invalid Data", 400
       return jsonify({'sum': data['a'] + data['b']}), 200
    except Exception as e:
       return "Invalid Data", 400
```

The `all()` function returns `True` if all items in an iterable evaluates to true